# Get value from server reponse swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, nsurl

I am new to Swift,
I want to get value of latitude and longitde from server reponse.

How do i get the value?

Here is my code:

```
WebServiceHelper.sharedInstance.makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", requestMethod: "GET", params: ["Key" : "value"], Success: { (JSON:Any) in

            print("Success Received data is: \(JSON)")

        }, Error: { (JSON:Any) in

            print("Error Received data is: \(JSON)")

        }) { (JSON:Any) in

            print("Header Received data is: \(JSON)")
        }
```

I am able to get server reponse Here it is:

```
Success Received data is: {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "suite": "Apt. 556",
    "city": "Gwenborough",
    "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    "geo": {
      "latitude": "-37.3159",
      "longitude": "81.1496"
    }
  },
  "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  "website": "hildegard.org",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
  }
}
```

***How do i get?***

Comment: JSONSerialization, and after that convert into your models

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019869/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-my-json-post/45020163#45020163

Comment: Can u plz help me to get syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this to get lat long :

```
if let result = JSON as? [String:AnyObject]{
        let address = result?["address"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        let geo = address?["geo"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        print(geo?["lng"])
        print(geo?["lat"]) }
```

Comment: I tried this code but control is not going inside if condition value of `JSON` is present

Comment: OK! Then you can use this without  " if " condition.

Comment: It gives error when i write this `let address = JSON["address"] as? [String:AnyObject]`

Comment: u have to write like this :
        let result = JSON as? [String:AnyObject]
        let address = result?["address"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        let geo = address?["geo"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        print(geo?["lng"])
        print(geo?["lat"])

Comment: same problem `result` is returning nil

Comment: but both are working at my end . Are using AFNetworking or alamofire or anything else to get response.